# Google Cloud Elastic Write Slow

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, google-compute-engine, mqtt

We are setting up our [Bevywise MQTT Broker](https://www.bevywise.com/mqtt-broker/) on Google Cloud Compute Instance either on docker or without docker and we are sending the data to the elastic Search engine deployed in another Compute instance.

We are sending data of 300 bytes in each packet and 1,00,000 messages. The broker receives the data in around 10  seconds and the write to the Elastic takes around 2 minutes.

However, when we set up the ElasticSearch on the same machine the write happens in around 25 seconds.

We are using 16 GB RAM and 4 CPU machines for the ElasticSearch Machine.

Is there anything we have to do to tweak the network connectivity between the two instances. We are using the same region for deploying both the Broker and the Elastic Search server.

I appreciate your advice.